# string.split() value passed to python3 module interprets '|' like \n\t\t\t\t. Why?

Tags: string, visual-studio, python-3.x, split

I'm using `lxml` to extract a long string value.
I pass this value to a `def` located in another `module` for `string.split('|')`.

When i got the `list[]` its `len()` was 0.
The problem was somehow the pipe was interpreted as '\n\t\t\t\t'.
When i do `string.split('\n\t\t\t\t')`, problem solved, crisis avoided.

I know its a representation of escape sequences.
But why?
I know i didn't voluntarily changed this in any of my code.

!!! EDIT !!!

Sorry for the trouble, someone kept editing my `xml` file from the network...
I guess they thought it was funny...

Comment: You should check if it's actually the same character. There are so many lookalike characters in unicode... I just tried it and had no problem splitting a string on pipes with Python 3.5

Comment: I use python 3.4.4

Comment: Can you post more code? The entire function being called would be appreciated, as well as an example string.

Comment: Please clarify. Is there still a problem or was the problem due to the edits via the network?

Comment: The changes were not introduced by the interpreter but rather by a praknkster in the network, I debuuged him. So no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes were not introduced by the interpreter but rather by a prankster in the network, I debuuged him. So no problem.